# Jquery if condition validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var text = jQuery('#product-options-wrapper ul li:first label').text();
alert('text outside loop is' + text);
if(text == "Unstiched Blouse Fabric") {
alert('inside loop' + text);
}
```

Using above code, I'm getting only the alert message printed "text outside loop isUnstiched Blouse Fabric". What wrong with the if? What are the alternatives I can use here?

Comment: `if` is not a loop

Comment: `'text outside loop is'+text` does not have a space after `is`, ` "text outside loop is Unstiched Blouse Fabric"` has it.

Comment: check for a space before "Unstiched Blouse Fabric"

Comment: @Andrei: Original alert message is without space. I've written it here instead of copy-paste. Updated the question.

Comment: try `text = text.trim();`

Comment: @amitshree, okay, then there is something else we do not see in the question. At least I [cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/6etuya8h/) the error. Btw, always use `===` in js, `==` is kind of unreliable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have space before

> ' Unstiched Blouse Fabric'

make sure you either compare with same value (space before) or make a trim.

Comment: text.trim();  did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think compare strings are bad idea why don't you set some attribute like this

```
<label attribute="1">Unstiched Blouse Fabric</label>

var text = jQuery('#product-options-wrapper ul li:first label');

if($(text).prop("attribute") == 1) {
alert('inside condition' + $(text).text());
}
```